# と as verbs connector?

Tags: particle-と, manga

Me and my friend read manga in Japanese as a tool to study.
We are currently reading 進撃の巨人 and we had a problem understanding the role of the kana と mid sentence. Here is the manga panel for context and reference:
[image]

We weren't sure its exact role although we managed to have some grasp of the translation of that sentence.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's just the regular usage of the quoting-particle と. The same と in Xと言う, X と思う, Xと知る, etc. Yes と can also be the and-particle or the if-particle, but here it's just a regular usage of と as the [quoting-particle](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/how-to-speak-japanese/how-to-make-quotations-using-the-particle-in-japanese/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the same と as in と言う. Knowing *that* mankind lives beyond the walls.